# What makes my python code so slow (Linked List Cycle)?

Tags: python, data-structures

> Given a linked list, determine if it has a cycle in it.
>
> Follow up: Can you solve it without using extra space?

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    # @param head, a ListNode
    # @return a boolean
    def hasCycle(self, head):
        if head:
            walker, runner = head, head
            while((walker.next != None) and (runner.next != None) and (runner.next.next != None)):
                walker = walker.next
                runner = runner.next.next
                if walker == runner:
                    return True
        return False
```

I've seen many people run their code in 100ms, however to me, time doubles. So how can I improve my code inspired by the same idea of two pointers.

Update:
Sharing a code I've just seen that implements in 130ms using try...except..., very interesting.

```
class Solution:
# @param head, a ListNode
# @return a boolean
def hasCycle(self, head):
    try:
        fast = head.next.next
        slow = head.next

        while fast != slow:
            fast = fast.next.next
            slow = slow.next

        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: Could you change the while loop like while (walker and runner and runner.next) and tell if there's a change

Comment: Which *"many people"*? What approach have they taken? Does it differ to yours, and how? Have you analysed the complexity (*"big-O"*) of their code vs. yours?

Comment: Where did you get these numbers? You've implemented canonical solution for the problem, so I don't see why your code should be slow

Comment: Well there is a distribution diagram provided by leetcode which suggests there are clearly two groups of people that implement the code with average time of 100ms and 200ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception handling is generally pretty fast in python, to the point where if the condition that would throw an exception is pretty rare, it is faster to handle the exception than constantly check the condition.

In your code you have several conditionals to see if the walker or runner is at the end (or near end) of the list - a "Look Before You Leap" approach.

Instead, you can throw out all those checks and just realize if something does throw an `AttributeError` when you try to access `next`, you are done looking for a loop and you can just quit and return `False`. You can see in the faster example code that they implement this, and it outperforms the approach with the constant checking.

You can also see a difference if you disassemble your solution:

```
>>> import dis
>>> a = Solution()
>>> dis.dis(a.hasCycle)
  5           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (head)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE      114

  6           6 LOAD_FAST                1 (head)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (head)
             12 ROT_TWO             
             13 STORE_FAST               2 (walker)
             16 STORE_FAST               3 (runner)

  7          19 SETUP_LOOP              92 (to 114)
        >>   22 LOAD_FAST                2 (walker)
             25 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
             28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             31 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
             34 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE      110
             37 LOAD_FAST                3 (runner)
             40 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
             43 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             46 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
             49 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE      110
             52 LOAD_FAST                3 (runner)
             55 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
             58 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
             61 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             64 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
             67 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE      110

  8          70 LOAD_FAST                2 (walker)
             73 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
             76 STORE_FAST               2 (walker)

  9          79 LOAD_FAST                3 (runner)
             82 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
             85 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
             88 STORE_FAST               3 (runner)

 10          91 LOAD_FAST                2 (walker)
             94 LOAD_FAST                3 (runner)
             97 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
            100 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       22

 11         103 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (True)
            106 RETURN_VALUE        
            107 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           22
        >>  110 POP_BLOCK           
            111 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 114)

 12     >>  114 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (False)
            117 RETURN_VALUE
```

And compare it to the faster try/except version:

```
>>> b = Solution()
>>> dis.dis(b.hasCycle)
 18           0 SETUP_EXCEPT            69 (to 72)

 19           3 LOAD_FAST                1 (head)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
             12 STORE_FAST               2 (fast)

 20          15 LOAD_FAST                1 (head)
             18 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
             21 STORE_FAST               3 (slow)

 22          24 SETUP_LOOP              37 (to 64)
        >>   27 LOAD_FAST                2 (fast)
             30 LOAD_FAST                3 (slow)
             33 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
             36 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       63

 23          39 LOAD_FAST                2 (fast)
             42 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
             45 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
             48 STORE_FAST               2 (fast)

 24          51 LOAD_FAST                3 (slow)
             54 LOAD_ATTR                0 (next)
             57 STORE_FAST               3 (slow)
             60 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           27
        >>   63 POP_BLOCK           

 26     >>   64 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (True)
             67 RETURN_VALUE        
             68 POP_BLOCK           
             69 JUMP_FORWARD             8 (to 80)

 27     >>   72 POP_TOP             
             73 POP_TOP             
             74 POP_TOP             

 28          75 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (False)
             78 RETURN_VALUE        
             79 END_FINALLY         
        >>   80 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             83 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see that the latter has less instructions overall, and fewer branches (POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE) which are expensive.